# WebService Call Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, rest

I want to make a call to a webservice with jquery, for add a new product in a customer. 
the web service url is http://www.tiny.com.br/api2/produto.incluir.php

and need to pass two parameters a client id, named token and product informations in a xml format, this request is in correct format?

I only get errors, how can i pass these parameters?

This is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnCallWebService").click(function (event) {
            var wsUrl = "http://www.tiny.com.br/api2/produto.incluir.php;

            var soapRequest ={token:'***', produto :'<produto>'
                    &'<codigo>223435780</codigo> '
                    &'<descricao>Caneta 001</descricao>'
                    &'<un>Pc</un>'
                    &'<vlr_unit>1.68</vlr_unit>'
                    &'<preco_custo>1.23</preco_custo>'
                &'  <peso_bruto>0.2</peso_bruto>'
                &'  <peso_liq>0.18</peso_liq>'
                &'  <class_fiscal>1000.01.01</class_fiscal>'
                &'  <origem>0</origem>'
                &'  <estoque>10</estoque>'
                &'  <tipo>P</tipo>'
                &'  <gtin>223435780</gtin>'
                &'  <gtinEmbalagem>54546</gtinEmbalagem>'
                &'</produto>'};

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: wsUrl,
                contentType: "text/xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: soapRequest,
                success: processSuccess,
                error: processError
            });

        });
    });

    function processSuccess(data, status, req) {
        if (status == "success")
            $("#response").text($(req.responseXML).find("HelloResult").text());
    }

    function processError(data, status, req) {
        alert(req.responseText + " " + status);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Are request and response pages sitting on the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error. In js we use '+' for concatenating strings and not '&'

```
var soapRequest ={token:'***', produto :'<produto>'
                    +'<codigo>223435780</codigo> '
                    +'<descricao>Caneta 001</descricao>'
                    +'<un>Pc</un>'
                    +'<vlr_unit>1.68</vlr_unit>'
                    +'<preco_custo>1.23</preco_custo>'
                +'  <peso_bruto>0.2</peso_bruto>'
                +'  <peso_liq>0.18</peso_liq>'
                +'  <class_fiscal>1000.01.01</class_fiscal>'
                +'  <origem>0</origem>'
                +'  <estoque>10</estoque>'
                +'  <tipo>P</tipo>'
                +'  <gtin>223435780</gtin>'
                +'  <gtinEmbalagem>54546</gtinEmbalagem>'
                +'</produto>'};
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Abhidev said, there is one `"` missing on the of the web service url.